# My batch code crashes after trying to go to the :apps label

Tags: batch-file, crash

I am programming something for my friends but my batch code keeps crashing.

Can someone help?

Here's the code:

```bash
@echo off
title xinsOS - Boot
echo.
goto load

:load
cls
if exist colour.txt (
    goto loadColour
) else (
    color 7
    goto desktop
)

:loadColour
cls
< colour.txt (
    set /p colour=
)
color %colour%
goto desktop

::Oh, you checked the code...
::while your here i could say this is just an hobby
::it will never be an bootable OS

:desktop
cd "%userprofile%\Documents\xinsOS"
cls
title Desktop
echo                                        Desktop
echo.
echo ([1]) Apps
echo ([2]) Info about the CREATOR
echo ([3]) SystemInfo
echo ([4]) Shutdown and Reboot
choice /N /C:1234
if errorlevel 255 goto desktop
if errorlevel 4 goto shutdown
if errorlevel 3 goto sysInfo
if errorlevel 2 goto CREATORinfo
if errorlevel 1 goto apps
if errorlevel 0 goto desktop

:sysInfo
cls
title System info
echo                                        System Info
echo.
echo.
echo Operating system: xinsOS v0.2
echo RAM: 16MB
echo CPU: XINS-I
echo Computer name: XINS-PC-001
echo PC-SERIAL-NUMBER: 0101-1011-1101-1010
pause>nul
goto desktop                

:apps
cd DownloadedApps
if exist "xinsPad\xinsPad.bat" (
    cls
    title Apps - xinsOS
    echo.
    echo                                        Apps
    echo.
    echo ([1]) xinsSettings
    echo ([2]) xinsPad
    echo ([3]) App Store
    echo ([4]) Back
    choice /N /C:1234
    if errorlevel 255 goto apps
    if errorlevel 4 goto desktop
    if errorlevel 3 goto StartXinsPad
    if errorlevel 2 goto appstore
    if errorlevel 1 goto xinssettings
    if errorlevel 0 goto apps
) else (
    echo hi
)

:xinssettings
cls
title Settings - xinsOS
echo.
echo.
echo ([1]) Colors
echo ([2]) Language
echo ([3]) Back
choice /N /C:123
if errorlevel 255 goto xinssettings
if errorlevel 3 goto apps
if errorlevel 2 goto language
if errorlevel 1 goto colors
if errorlevel 0 goto xinssettings

:colors
cls
title Choose colour - xinsOS
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Choose Colour:
echo.
echo.
echo ([1]) Red
echo ([2]) Blue
echo ([3]) Matrix style
echo ([4]) Purple
echo ([5]) Aqua
echo ([6]) Back
choice /N /C:123456
if errorlevel 255 goto colors
if errorlevel 6 goto xinssettings
if errorlevel 5 goto SaveAqua
if errorlevel 4 goto SavePurple
if errorlevel 3 goto SaveGreen
if errorlevel 2 goto SaveBlue
if errorlevel 1 goto SaveRed
if errorlevel 0 goto colors

:SaveRed
color 4
echo Saving color settings...
set colour=4
(
    echo %colour%
)>colour.txt
goto colors

:SaveBlue
color 1
echo Saving color settings...
set colour=1
(
    echo %colour%
)>colour.txt
goto colors

:SaveGreen
color 2
echo Saving color settings...
set colour=2
(
    echo %colour%
)>colour.txt
goto colors

:SavePurple
color 5
echo Saving color settings...
set colour=5
(
    echo %colour%
)>colour.txt
goto colors

:SaveAqua
color 3
echo Saving color settings...
set colour=3
(
    echo %colour%
)>colour.txt
goto colors

:language
cls
title Language Settings - xinsOS
echo.
echo.
echo ([1]) English (currently chosen)
echo ([2]) Deutsch/German

:appstore
cls
title App Store - xinsOS
echo.
echo                                        App Store
echo.
echo ([1]) xinsPad 
echo ([2]) Back
choice /N /C:12
if errorlevel 255 goto appstore
if errorlevel 2 goto apps
if errorlevel 1 goto downloadxinspad
if errorlevel 0 goto appstore

:downloadxinspad
cls
title Downloading xinsPad - xinsOS
echo.
echo                                        xinsPad Download
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Starting Download
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Starting Download.
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Starting Download..
timeout /t 2 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Starting Download...
timeout /t 4 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Starting Download    - 0KB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading.   - 400KB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading..  - 600KB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading... - 800KB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading    - 1.2MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading.   - 1.6MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading..  - 2.0MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading... - 2.4MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading    - 2.8MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cd "%userprofile%\Documents\xinsOS\DownloadedApps"
mkdir xinsPad
xcopy "%userprofile%\Documents\xinsOS\Dependencies\xinsPad" "%userprofile%\Documents\xinsOS\DownloadedApps\xinsPad" > nul
cls
echo Downloading.   - 3.2MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading..  - 3.6MB/s
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Downloading... - 4.0MB/s
timeout /t 5 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo Finished!
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
goto appstore

:CREATORinfo
cls
title INFO ABOUT THE CREATOR - XINSOS
echo.
echo                 INFO ABOUT THE CREATOR
echo.
echo xinsOS was made by a 10 year old, now 11 year old. (No really, it was). His name is Max Atkinson. He is from Germany.
echo He was born in February 16th 2012, in Germany.
echo He first started programming at 6 years old, just right after getting his first laptop, which 4 years later, he is still programming on.
echo He saw a video from IProgramInCPP, who made his own "OS" in Batch.
echo That was his inspiration to create his own. He first made maxOS, which was discontinued 2 days after initial release.
echo  No download is available.
echo Then he made BeeOS, which was discontinued 1 week after initial release.
echo No download available.
echo His video which he made which was called: "Check if Updates are available. | BeeOS", was very cringe.
echo His video didn't make any sense. Here is his youtube channel:
echo https://www.youtube.com/@beeos2639
echo Then he made choOS, which was discontinued 2 weeks after initial release.
echo He just didn't have any motivation anymore.
echo But 1 year later, HE IS BACK!
echo.
echo With xinsOS!
echo He himself said: "I do not have any dates where xinsOS will be discontinued. But I hope you guys enjoy this "OS" made by me!"
echo That was the end of info about the CREATOR. We all at the xinsOS Team, wish you a rest of the day/night.
echo And enjoy the "OS"!
echo PS: this is just a hobby, Max doesn't ever plan to make this a bootable and famous OS. But you never know, maybe he will!
echo Press 1 to see the credits.
echo ([1]) Credits
echo ([2]) Back
choice /N /C:12
if errorlevel 255 goto CREATORinfo
if errorlevel 2 goto desktop
if errorlevel 1 goto credits
if errorlevel 0 goto CREATORinfo

:credits
cls
title CREDITS - xinsOS
echo.
echo.
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo CREDITS
echo.
echo.
echo.
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo MAX ATKINSON - Creator of the OS.
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo KAEJ KAM - Creator of the credits.
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo Compo and Stephan (from StackOverflow) - helping me with the code
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo THE END OF CREDITS
timeout /t 3 /nobreak > nul
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
echo.
cls
goto CREATORinfo

:shutdown
cls
title WDYWTD - xinsOS
echo What do you want to do?
echo.
echo ([1]) shutdown
echo ([2]) reboot
echo ([3]) back
choice /N /C:123
if errorlevel 255 goto shutdown
if errorlevel 3 goto desktop
if errorlevel 2 goto reboot
if errorlevel 1 exit
if errorlevel 0 goto shutdown

:reboot
cls
title reboot
echo.
echo.
echo rebooting.
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo rebooting..
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
echo rebooting...
timeout /t 1 /nobreak > nul
cls
goto "%userprofile%\Documents\xinsOS"
start desktop.cmd
exit
pause>nul
```

I tried to go to the label `:apps`, but my code keeps crashing and I don't know why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `)` in `([1])` is being considered the end of the `if` statement, so it's trying to run `xinsSettings` as a command, resulting in the error `xinsSettings was unexpected at this time.`

The easy way around this is to never try to display parentheses while you're inside of parentheses, but you can also open up Find-and-Replace in your text editor and replace all instances of `])` with `]^)` to escape the `)` and tell the interpreter to not treat it like a regular parenthesis.

```
echo ([1]^) xinsSettings
echo ([2]^) xinsPad
echo ([3]^) App Store
echo ([4]^) Back
```

etc.

Comment: THAT WAS ALL I HAD TO DO??? Your the best, you mind if I put you in the credits?

Comment: You are welcome to if you'd like, but I'd prefer if you clicked the check mark next to my answer to mark it as the solution. :)